# Why does Android Studio believe my App Engine module is an Android app?

Tags: google-app-engine, android-studio, gradle

I have a project which contains

- an Android app module
- an App Engine (Cloud Endpoints) module

When I created the project with an older version of Android Studio, it created a reference between the modules, which I removed. Before I did this, I also tried raising the minimum Version in the app module to 21, but Android Studio or LINT somehow still believes my App Engine module was an app and marks code like

- `list.isEmpty()`
- `new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>()`

with something like `Call required API level 9 (current min is 1): (...)`.

The project compiles fine, but the errors are underlined in red and show up in LINT.

Neither in the project gradle nor the module gradle I can see anything suspicious. Any idea what the problem could be or where to search and fix this?

For completeness, here are the gradle files:

Projct:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

App Engine Module:

```
// https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-plugin

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.9.30'
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter();
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'appengine'

dependencies {
    appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.30'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints:1.9.30'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints-deps:1.9.30'
    compile 'com.google.appengine.tools:appengine-gcs-client:0.5'
    compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
    compile 'com.googlecode.objectify:objectify:5.1.3'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-simplexml:1.9.0'
    compile 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.6.0'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-parent:1.7.10' // required for JJWT
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-nop:1.7.10' // suppress all internal logging in JJWT
}

appengine {
    downloadSdk = true
    appcfg {
        oauth2 = true
    }
    endpoints {
        getClientLibsOnBuild = true
        getDiscoveryDocsOnBuild = true
    }
}
```

App Module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "cc.closeup.android.test"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
}
```

Comment: How did you resolve the issue? I am getting the same error.

Comment: @Chebyr You can't solve this I believe. I tried to mess with this and managed to remove the app module, but automated tests won't run anymore once you do this. If it disturbs you, you can use IntelliJ IDEA instead Android Studio, which is the same, but better supports pure Java apps. But for App Engine projects, App Engine specific gradle commands may be missing then.